# Swagger annotations describe default response of an operation

Tags: java, swagger

I want to define "default" response of an operation with @ApiResponse annotation.
I'm using swagger annotations 1.5.x and want to generate something like this (look at default response):

```
"get" : {
    ...
    "responses" : {
      "200" : {
        "description" : "successful operation",
        "schema" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/Address"
          }
        }
      },
      "default" : {
        "description" : "unsuccessful operation",
        "schema" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  }
```

But I don't know how to do that, because @ApiResponse(code = ...) annotation expects only numbers not Strings.

My Java code:

```
 ...
 @ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful operation", response = Address.class, responseContainer = "List"),
    @ApiResponse(code = "default", message = "unsuccessful operation", response = ErrorMessage.class),
...})
public Response getAllAddresses() throws SQLException {
...
}
```

So is there any way to specify "default" ApiResponse in Swagger annotations 1.5.x?

Comment: I have encountered the same issue. Have you managed to find an answer?
All that I can find is this issue - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/971

Comment: Hi, I still haven't come anywhere with this problem. Currently I'm using GitHub Flavored Markdown to specify default responses in SwaggerUI header. I think that I'll slowly move to OpenAPI 3.0 spec.